# C# tinting an ImageBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, textures, imagebrush

Is it somehow possible to change the hue of an imagebrush. I'm currently using an imagebrush to create a texture material in wpf 3d. To get selection and grouping effects, i need up to three materials per model. This results in quite the performance hit. Here is the current code:

```
  DiffuseMaterial itemImageMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new ImageBrush(ItemTextures[nr]) { Stretch = Stretch.Fill });
  var meshGeom = new MeshGeometry3D();
  meshGeom.Positions = cubesPositions;
  meshGeom.TriangleIndices = cubesIndeces;
  GeometryModel3D geoMod = new GeometryModel3D();
  geoMod.Geometry = meshGeom;
  MaterialGroup mg = new MaterialGroup();
  mg.Children.Add(itemImageMaterial);
  if (applyGroupOverlay) mg.Children.Add(groupMaterials[groupNr]);
  if (applyHighlight) mg.Children.Add(highlightMaterials[highlightNr]);
  mg.Freeze();
  geoMod.Material = mg;
  (geoMod.Geometry as MeshGeometry3D).TextureCoordinates = cubesTextureCoords;
  Visual3DModel = geoMod;
```

nb. ItemTextures[nr] is a freezed BitmapImage

Hopefully there is a solution so that the code can look something like this:

```
  ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush(ItemTextures[nr]) { Stretch = Stretch.Fill }
  if (applyGroupOverlay){
    //tint brush here
  }
  if (applyHighlight) {
    //tint brush some more here
  }
  DiffuseMaterial itemImageMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(brush);
  var meshGeom = new MeshGeometry3D();
  meshGeom.Positions = cubesPositions;
  meshGeom.TriangleIndices = cubesIndeces;
  GeometryModel3D geoMod = new GeometryModel3D();
  geoMod.Geometry = meshGeom;
  geoMod.Material = itemImageMaterial;
  (geoMod.Geometry as MeshGeometry3D).TextureCoordinates = cubesTextureCoords;
```

This way, only a single material is needed to create the desired effects.